# Define a command with an odd number of braces

Tags: macros

In my code, I change to '2 columns' mode typing:

```
\twocolumn[{
```

I'm trying to simplify this code, by creating a new command:

```
\renewcommand{\twocolumn}{\twocolumn[{}
```

Is this possible to insert a bracket and a brace in this new command? I'm getting a lot of errors doing this.

Comment: My only question: Why do you want to do this? It looks weird ;-)

Comment: Why do you use `\twocolumn[{...}]` instead of `\twocolumn[...]`?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer +1. An answer seems to be beyond my imagination. :-)

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke: It could be possible with Plain TeX or with `xparse` approach, but I still don't know why this should be useful. Thanks ;-)

Comment: @Herbert Perhaps there's an optional argument inside the `[]` pair: as already noted, `xparse` would help with that.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I mean: OP's answer. I remember, that such a problem is considered in The TeXbook, by even saving a few keystrokes is not an argument to change the meaning of `\twocolumn` in this case. One should simply use a shorter name, e.g. `\def\ThisIsMuchMuchShorterNameOfTwocolumn{\twocolumn}`. ;-)

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke: Yeah, a much shorter name ;-)

Comment: @JosephWright: Sure, it is an optional argument. But why should it be also inside `{..}`?

Comment: @Herbert I meant if the set up is `\twocolumn[ ... \foo[ ... ] ... ]`, _i.e._ a nested optional argument. That will fail with the LaTeX2e approach to grabbing optionals but will work if done by `xparse`.

Comment: @JosephWright: Will you provide a solution?

Comment: @JosephWright: Sure, but that was my original question why he/she needs the `{...}`

Comment: The specific answer to your question is `NO', it is not possible to define a command with an odd number of braces in the specimen code you have provided. However, if you can provide a MWE with real requirement, then somebody can definitely help.

Comment: You obviously close the originally opened brackets `[` and `{`. Could you show a complete use of your code rather than just a snippet?

Comment: I'm a teacher, and always use latex to make my tests. In the preamble, always use \documentclass[a4paper, twocolumn, twoside]{article}.

Don't know why, but I don't like to use multicols. Unfortunately, some images are larger and I need to 'open space', changing the layout to one column. The \twocolumn[ seems to not work, but \twocolumn[{ do.

(edit: how to insert latex code in answers?)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The sequence

```
\renewcommand{\twocolumn}{\twocolumn[{}
```

would define a commmand `\twocolumn` that - among other
things - would call itself. You would get some sort of
recursive loop where compilation might terminate with
an error message `TeX capacity exceeded` or the like when
during recursion too many opening brackets and opening
braces got accumulated.

Besides this `\twocolumn` is a macro that might be used 
within macro-packages and the like. Redefining it might 
lead to problems with (package-)code where it is relied
on the original meaning of `\twocolumn`.

Perhaps defining your own macro for calling `\twocolumn`
might be an option:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\calltwocolumn{%
  \expandafter\twocolumn
  \expandafter[%
  \expandafter{%
  \romannumeral0\expandafter\@gobble\string} %
}%
\makeatother
```

The command `\calltwocolumn` would yield the following tokens:

```
  \expandafter\twocolumn
  \expandafter[%
  \expandafter{%
  \romannumeral0\expandafter\@gobble\string} %
```

The `\expandafter`-chain would turn on `\romannumeral`-expansion before `\twocolumn` would get carried out.
`\romannumeral`-expansion in turn would lead to stringifying and gobbling the
closing brace before terminating without delivering any token.

Some people are reluctant when it comes to using `\makeatletter`. 
You can avoid that using `\csname`:

```
\newcommand\calltwocolumn{%
  \expandafter\twocolumn
  \expandafter[%
  \expandafter{%
  \romannumeral0\csname @gobble\expandafter\endcsname\string} %
}%
```

You can as well avoid that using `\iffalse` as suggested by Gustavo Mezzetti:

```
\newcommand\calltwocolumn{%
  \expandafter\twocolumn
  \expandafter[%
  \expandafter{%
  \iffalse}\fi
}%
```

Comment: Clever trick; but the classic `\iffalse }\fi` (cf. _The TeXbook_, exercise 20.17) could be used instead of `\romannumeral0…`, couldn’t it?

Comment: Is there a tip to simplify
    }]\endtwocolumn
assuming that \endtwocolumn is already defined?

Comment: Well, in this case (1) `\iffalse` is properly paired with its `\fi`, and (2) the whole pair is buried inside a macro, which is either expanded or not (_tertium non datur_ :-) .

Comment: @UlrichDiez: can you provide a solution do the tail of the code?

How can I do }]/endtwocolumn eliminating the braces and brackets?