# Removing annoying braces/brackets

Tags: macros

I have a command that works with this syntax:

```
\startmycommand[{

nononononononononononon
nononononononononononon
nononononononononononon

}]\endmycommand
```

A user has provided a(n) (excellent) simplification to `\startmycommand`, as you can see above:

```
\newcommand\mynewstartcommand{%
  \expandafter\startmycommand
  \expandafter[%
  \expandafter{%
  \iffalse}\fi
}%
```

How can I do the same for `}]\endmycommand`?

Comment: Could you explain what the command does and why it has this uncommon syntax? Looks more like an environment to me … and why can’t you use simple search&replace to change the code in your document?

Comment: Hi, @Tobi. I agree, it's like an environment. This is the syntax for \twocolumn, that works with:

    \twocolumn[{
       nononononon
    }]

I don't know why this command requires brackets AND braces, but doesn't work if some of them are removed.

Comment: Actually `\twocolumn` does not require the braces. Only if the argument contains brackets the braces ar needed. I.e.: `\twocolumn[ok]`, `\twocolumn[not [ok]]`, `\twocolumn[{now [ok]}]`. This is because TeX can’t finde the end of the argument otherwise and this rule applies to all optional arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for something like the following example:

```
\long\def\mynewstartcommand#1\endmycommand{%
  \startcommand[{#1}]\endmycommand
}

\mynewstartcommand

  nononononononononononon
  nononononononononononon
  nononononononononononon

\endmycommand
```

But the question is not too clear, what's the regular content of the argument, what's the purpose of the empty lines in the argument, what is the desired syntax?

Comment: The question is a follow-up of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/257721/define-a-command-with-an-odd-number-of-braces, I think, however, the purpose of this syntax request isn't clear yet (at least not to me)

Answer (score 0):

@Heiko Oberdiek, your answer has worked fine here.

A minimal example to ilustrate how I'm using it – with your suggestion:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twocolumn, twoside]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\long\def\mynewstartcommand#1\endmycommand{%
  \twocolumn[{#1}]\vspace*{10 mm}
}

\begin{document}


\mynewstartcommand

\begin{minipage}{0.795\paperwidth}
\begin{minipage}[t][][b]{0.45\linewidth}
\lipsum[1]
\end{minipage}\qquad~\qquad
\begin{minipage}[t][][b]{0.45\linewidth}
\lipsum[2]
\vspace*{40 mm}
\end{minipage}
\end{minipage}


\lipsum[3]

\endmycommand


\end{document}
```